# Find $1 \le a < b \le n$ such that $a\cdot b + a + b = n\cdot (n+1)/2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, diophantine-equations, integer-lattices

> Find $1 \le a < b \le  n$ such that $$a\cdot b + a + b = \frac{n\cdot (n+1)}2$$

Is there a more efficient way than picking $a$ or $b$ and trying all values between $1$ and $n$ ?

Comment: Since that is an increasing function of $a$ and $b$ you can certainly limit your search to a much smaller range, and adjust your tests efficiently.

Comment: @EthanBolker thank you for your comment. Can you please say more?

Comment: In light of @CYAries answer and comments there it seems that you want an integer solution for large $n$. That's a factoring problem known to be hard, so my observation won't be much help.

Answer (score 6):

$(a+1)(b+1)=\dfrac{n^2+n+2}{2}$.

If $a$ and $b$ are restricted to integers, consider the factors of $\dfrac{n^2+n+2}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you for a great insight. Isn't finding factors of (n^2 + n + 2)/2 on the order of the square root of that, which is basically still O(n)?

Comment: You may find the prime factorization of the number. For example, $1176=2^3\times 3\times7^2$. Its positive factors are those numbers of form $2^a3^b7^c$, where $a\in\{0,1,2,3\}$, $b\in\{0,1\}$ and $c\in\{0,1,2\}$.

Comment: Sure, but to find prime factors of `x`, we still need to explore all numbers below the square root of `x`, which in this case is on the order of magnitude of `n`. No? (My question is whether there is a more efficient way than O(n).)

Comment: Yes. If $n$ is large, it is still very difficult.

Comment: @גלעדברקן:  He has already restricted the search to about $\frac n{\sqrt 2}$, so that is an improvement.  You also know that you need a factor greater than $\frac n2$ because otherwise the other factor will be greater than $n$.  Both these ignore the addition of $n+2$, but that is small for large $n$.